# How to document a web service API?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java, java2wsdl

I have a problem with documenting my web service API. It is written in Java, then I use `java2wsdl` go generate wsdl file, etc.

How do I create a documentation for this? I need some documentation that I could give to the user. Do I document my initial Java code?

How should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **WSDL** file have all details regarding the service. It clearly states input, output for your service. Along with this you can also provide details of your service in form of **wiki/doc** which explains the service, expected input, response and error codes etc.

If you need you can also generate JavaDoc for your project.

Comment: I'm very suspicious regarding the wiki doc. I mean, I need to keep track of API changes somehow, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is any other option...you will have to keep updating your docs whenever there is any change in service.